# multiple key value pairs in dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create multiple key : value pairs in a dict comprehension like this:

```
{'ID': (e[0]), 'post_author': (e[1]) for e in wp_users}
```

I am receiving `"missing ','"`

I have also tried it this way:

```
[{'ID': (e[0]), 'post_author': (e[1])} for e in wp_users]
```

I then receive `"list indices must be integers, not str"`

Which I understand, but not sure the best way in correcting this and if multiple key : value pairs is possible with dict comprehensions?

Comment: Second way works fine for me. What type is `wp_users`?

Comment: Brackets around `e[0]` are useless here

Comment: When I try to access 'post_author' for example: `wp_users_list['post_author']` is when I get `"list indices must be integers, not str"`

Comment: because you are creating a list not a dict on the second option. Try looping through it, or `wp_users_list[0]['post_author']`

Comment: Answer is here in the comments, ignore the posted answers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension can only ever produce **one** key-value pair per iteration. The trick then is to produce an extra loop to separate out the pairs:

```
{k: v for e in wp_users for k, v in zip(('ID', 'post_author'), e)}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result = {}
for e in wp_users:
    for k, v in zip(('ID', 'post_author'), e):
        result[k] = v
```

Note that this just repeats the two keys with each of your `wp_users` list, so you are continually replacing the same keys with new values! You may as well just take the last entry in that case:

```
result = dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), wp_users[-1]))
```

You didn’t share what output you *expected* however.

If the idea was to have a list of dictionaries, each with two keys, then you want a list comprehension of the above expression applied to each `wp_users` entry:

```
result = [dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), e)) for e in wp_users]
```

That produces the same output as your own, second attempt, but now you have a *list* of dictionaries. You’ll have to use integer indices to get to one of the dictionaries objects or use further loops.

Answer (score 21):

I came across this old question by accident, and I'm not convinced by the accepted answer.

## Accepted answer

What is disturbing with the accepted answer? Consider this:

```
>>> wp_users = [(1, 'Bill'), (2, 'Bob')]
>>> {k: v for e in wp_users for k, v in zip(('ID', 'post_author'), e)}
{'ID': 2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}
```

- First iteration over `wp_users`, `e =  (1, 'Bill')`, the dict is `{'ID':1, 'post_author': 'Bill'}`
- Second iteration over `wp_users`, `e =  (2, 'Bob')`, the dict is totally overwritten to `{'ID':2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}`

On every iteration, all the values of the dictonary are overwritten. You can avoid a loop and jump directly to the last element of `wp_users`:

```
>>> {k: v for e in wp_users for k, v in zip(('ID', 'post_author'), e)}
{'ID': 2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}
```

Or:

```
>>> dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), wp_users[-1]))
{'ID': 2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}
```

I think that's not what you want.

What you are trying to achieve remains unclear, but I see two options: you have a list of users `(id, post_author)` and you want to create either a list of dictionaries (one dict per user) or a dictionary of tuples (one tuple per field). You can see the first version as a presentation by lines, and the second as a presentation by columns of the same data.

## A list of dictionaries

Try this:

```
>>> [dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), user)) for user in wp_users]
[{'ID': 1, 'post_author': 'Bill'}, {'ID': 2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}]
```

For each `user`, `zip` will create tuples `('ID', id)` and `('post_author', author)` and `dict` will generate the dictionaries. Now you can access to the fields like that:

```
>>> ds = [dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), user)) for user in wp_users]
>>> ds[0]['post_author']
'Bill'
```

## A dictionary of tuples

That's more unusual, but you might want one dictionary whose values are tuples:

```
>>> dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), zip(*wp_users)))
{'ID': (1, 2), 'post_author': ('Bill', 'Bob')}
```

`zip(*wp_users)` simply creates a list of tuples `[(id1, id2, ...), (post_author1, post_author2, ...)]` and the rest is similar to the previous version.

```
>>> d = dict(zip(('ID', 'post_author'), zip(*wp_users)))
>>> d['post_author'][0]
'Bill'
```

## Bonus

To extract a column from the line view:

```
>>> [d['ID'] for d in ds]
[1, 2]
```

To extract a line from the column view:

```
>>> {k:vs[1] for k, vs in d.items()}
{'ID': 2, 'post_author': 'Bob'}
```

Comment: See, that’s the trouble with questions that lack a proper [mcve], you don’t always see that the inputs don’t make sense for what they are asking. It is indeed far from clear what it is the OP as expected as output.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the second version is creating a **list** of dictionaries, not just **one** dictionary. You are trying to access a list with a string, which raises the error:

```
>>> obj = [{'data1': 67, 'data2': 78}]
>>> obj[0]['data1']
67
>>> obj['data1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>>
```

Instead, just access the second version as `wp_list[0]['post_author'], and it should work fine:

```
>>> wp_users = ('Bob', 'Joe', 'Sally')
>>> wp_list = [{'ID': (e[0]), 'post_author': (e[1])} for e in wp_users]
>>> wp_list[0]['post_author']
'o'
>>> wp_list[1]['post_author']
'o'
>>> wp_list[2]['post_author']
'a'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution for python >= 3.9 (change the key and values as you want, although i recommend keeping the tuple unpacked even if you're going to build a new tuple)

```
from itertools import tee
a,b = tee(tuple_collection)
c = {k:v for k,v in a} | {v:k for k,v in b}
```

I'm not actually sure this is actually as efficient as a single for to place the two keys in the same dict. Depends on how good tee is and how optimized | can be i suppose. Sure looks clean though.

if you're on python 3.5+ you can use

```
c = dict(**{k:v for k,v in a}, **{v:k for k,v in b})
```

or

```
c = {k:v for k,v in a}
c.update({v:k for k,v in b})
```

instead.